# Erro ao adicionar chave estrangeira em tabela SQL

Tags: sql, syntax-error

Olá, estou tentando adicionar uma chave estrangeira em uma tabela já criada e ela dá o seguinte erro:

> Error(s), warning(s):
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'foreign'.

testei algumas modificações na sintaxe, mas não estou conseguindo corrigir o erro.

Esse é o código que estou usando:

```
create table justificativa
(
    CODIGO              char(5)     not null, 
    IDSt                char(5)     not null,
    primary key(CODIGO)
);

create table situacao
(
    IDSt                char(5)     not null,   
    ORIGEM          char(5) not null,
    CODIGO              char(5)     not null,
    IDC     char(5)             not null,
    primary key(IDSt),
    foreign key (CODIGO) references justificativa
);


ALTER TABLE justificativa
ADD FOREIGN KEY (IDSt)
REFERENCES   situacao(IDSt);
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia por que isso está acontecendo?

Estou usando o rextester.com para rodar o código.

Comment: qual banco de dados você está utilizando? em qual query ou linha está resultando o erro?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que faltou referenciar a coluna na criação da tabela Situação ou então seu banco de dados não suporta a sintaxe que você está tentando usar.

É possível fazer isso no MySQL:

```
create table situacao
(
    IDSt char(5) not null,   
    ORIGEM char(5) not null,
    CODIGO char(5) not null,
    IDC char(5) not null,
    primary key(IDSt),
    foreign key (CODIGO) references justificativa(CODIGO)
);
```

Em outros bancos, a sintaxe pode variar um pouco (testei no SQL Server aqui):

```
create table situacao
(
    IDSt char(5) not null,   
    ORIGEM char(5) not null,
    CODIGO char(5) not null foreign key references justificativa(CODIGO),
    IDC char(5) not null,
    primary key(IDSt)
);
```

Quando se trata de chaves estrangeiras, gosto de definir ela fora da criação da tabela, alterando a tabela criada com alter table para evitar de referenciar uma tabela que ainda não foi criar e resultar em algum erro:

```
create table situacao
(
    IDSt char(5) not null,   
    ORIGEM char(5) not null,
    CODIGO char(5) not null,
    IDC char(5) not null,
    primary key(IDSt)
);    

ALTER TABLE situacao
ADD FOREIGN KEY (IDSt)
REFERENCES justificativa(CODIGO);
```

---

Estou considerando que esse exemplo é para fins didáticos, pois uma tabela referenciando a gera uma [dependência circular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652152/mysql-circular-dependency-in-foreign-key-constraints).